# Using multiple requests with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use `request-promise` module to check multiple web sites. If I use `Promise.all` as per design, promise returns with first reject. What is the proper way to execute multiple request tasks and wait all requests to finish whether they are fulfilled or rejected? I have come up with following two functions.

`CheckSitesV1` returns exception due to one rejected promise. However `CheckSitesV2` waits all promises to finish whether they are they are fulfilled or rejected. I will appreciate if you can comment whether the code I write makes sense. I am using NodeJS v7.9.0

```
const sitesArray = ['http://www.example.com','https://doesnt-really-exist.org','http://www.httpbin.org'];

async function CheckSitesV1() {
    let ps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++) {
        let ops = {
            method: 'GET',
            uri:sitesArray[i],
        };
        const resp = await rp.get(ops);
        ps.push(resp);
    }
    return Promise.all(ps)
}

function CheckSitesV2() {
    let ps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++) {
        let ops = {
            method: 'GET',
            uri:sitesArray[i],
        };
        ps.push(rp.get(ops));
    }
    return Promise.all(ps.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
}

CheckSitesV1().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('Exception: ' + e);
});

CheckSitesV2().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log('Exception: ' + e);
});
```

Comment: The "proper" way is the way that does exactly what you want to happen. `CheckSitesV1` does not resolve the promises in parallel whereas `CheckSitesV2` does. Which behavior do you want?

Comment: I want to check all sites whether I can reach it or not. `CheckSitesV1` returns rejected when one of the requests fails. I don't know if `CheckSitesV2` follows best practices. I didn't quite get async await in JS

Comment: But do you want the requests to be executed in parallel or in series? Because that's what the difference between these two solutions are. Also, I don't believe the first one actually doesn't do what you want. As soon as a promise is rejected, `CheckSitesV1` will throw: https://jsfiddle.net/gbw0c7x1/

Comment: It doesn't matter for me to run them in parallel or in series. I would like to learn of course how to do both. First one doesn't request rest of URLs if it encounters an error. Because AFAIK, `Promise.all` returns with first rejection.

Comment: Sorry, forgot already that you were aware that the first one doesn't do what you want. However I'm confused now... what is your question really about? What is it that you are asking about `CheckSitesV1` if you already know that it doesn't do what you want it to do? FWIW, the reason why it doesn't work is not because of `Promise.all` (calling `Promise.all` is unnecessary here, you should be doing `return ps;`) but because `await` will throw an error if the promise that is awaited is rejected. If `CheckSitesV2` does what you want then why not just use it? Would you prefer async/await?

Comment: I am trying to understand how to make `CheckSitesV1` work by using async await just like `CheckSitesV2` So that I will have a flexibility to run the requests in parallel or in series. I am sorry for being so naive. This async await stuff didn't click for me yet :\

Comment: `await` either returns the resolved value or throws the reject reason. So you have to catch the error: `try { ps.push(await rp.get(ops)); } catch (error) { ps.push(error); }`. [More about `await` in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
function CheckSitesV2() {
    let ps = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++) {
        let ops = {
            method: 'GET',
            uri:sitesArray[i],
        };
        ps.push(rp.get(ops));
    }
    return Promise.all(ps.map(p => p.catch(e => e)))
}
```

is totally fine. I can only suggest refactor a bit for readability:

```js
function CheckSitesV2() {
  let ps = sitesArray
    .map(site => rp.get({method: 'GET', uri: site}).catch(e => e));

  return Promise.all(ps);
}
```

Regarding async try this

```js
async function CheckSitesV1() {
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++) {
        let opts = {
          method: "GET",
          uri: sitesArray[i]
        };
        const resp = await rp.get(opts).catch(e => e);
        results.push(resp);
    }
    return results;
}

CheckSitesV1().then(console.log)
```

Comment: With `async`/`await` most people likely would use `try`-`catch` though. Even when it's weird and more bloated than `.catch()` :-)

Comment: @Bergi the whole purpose of `catch(e=>e)` is to suppress the error and pass it on to the next successful `then` as regular result.

Comment: Yes of course, but you could also do `try { results.push(await rp.get(opts)); } catch(e) { results.push(e); }` (which I presume would be more idiomatic, even if I don't like it)